# Run an emulator on an AMD processor

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created an emulator with `Google API` of `API 25` in `Android Studio` and my machine has `AMD` `Processor`. Can I run the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,Just Follow below things

open Android AVD Manager: Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager and create an emulator:

-Create Virtual Device

-Choose any hardware

-Now in system image you need to click on the "Other Images" tab

-Select an image to install. IMPORTANT: Notice that for AMD in the "ABI" column it has to say: ARM EABI v7a or ARM 64 v8a

-Install it and restart Android Studio

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

On `AMD processor` you may be run ARM architecture Android Image not Intel but
emulator become very slow.

[image]

**better way**

use `Genymotion emulator` for personal use, This work on both
Intel VT-X  and AMD-V technology.

Answer (score 0):

after running 15 emulator follow this [blog post](https://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-emulators-for-pc-655308/) finally, I can run my android emulator super fast on my AMD Ryzen 5 1600 machine.

- window emulator very slow and crash and old
- Genymotion Emulator is expensive without free
- Bluestack cannot inspect with "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" error and have problem with keyboard
- Nox Emulator cannot connect to browser to inspect
- MEmu cannot connect to browser to inspect
- [Andy Emulator](https://www.andyroid.net) the only one can work perfectly

trust me, no seeding, just take 3 days investigate on this

[image]